# Broken Image styles don't generate

Tags: media, 9

1. I am on Drupal 9.3
2. Set the Private file system path in `settings.php` file `$settings['file_private_path'] = '../private';`
3. Create a folder name outside the `"web"` folder named `"private"`
4. While uploading an image the original image is getting saved to the "private" folder but Image styles not getting generated, that is broken.
5. Attached is the screenshot image field[image].

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the "convert" effect on all image styles on my website which has an issue in Drupal 9. [This patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2786735#comment-13378964) fixed the issue for me.